# UWP C# Read 64Byte chuncks of data from Serial device

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port

I have an arduino device that reads data and sends it in 64Byte chunks.  At times it could be reading upto 4MB

```
Serial.write(data, 64);
```

I'm trying to read this data using a UWP app following the [Microsoft example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess/cs):

```
   private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, uint readBufferLength)
    {
        Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

        // Don't start any IO if we canceled the task
        lock (ReadCancelLock)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            // Cancellation Token will be used so we can stop the task operation explicitly
            // The completion function should still be called so that we can properly handle a canceled task
            DataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
            loadAsyncTask = DataReaderObject.LoadAsync(readBufferLength).AsTask(cancellationToken);
        }

        UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;

        while (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
        }

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            dataRead = new byte[bytesRead];
            DataReaderObject.ReadBytes(dataRead);
            ReadBytesCounter += bytesRead;

        }
```

I don't as the amount of data returned from the device is different each time I don't know the read buffer length. When I set the read buffer length to higher than 4MB it fails to return any data. When I set it lower than 4MB (say 32KB) it just returns that 32KB.

My questions are:

1. How do I get data to return when I don't know the read buffer length.
2. Is there no other way to read data from a serial device in UWP other than DataReaderObject.LoadAsync()? i.e a while loop where it continues to read data until no more is found? Or something like RS232_PollComport()?

Comment: You must improve the protocol so the reader code has a chance to get this right.  A simple way is to have the Arduino first send the count of bytes, then the actual bytes.  The reader can now read that count and loop, repeated calling LoadAsync() to get all the data.  Also the way the HTTP protocol works.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get data to return when I don't know the read buffer length.

I don't have a device for testing but try to update your code snippet like follows:

```
UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
while (bytesRead == ReadBufferLength)
{
    bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
}
if (DataReaderObject.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
{
    ReadBytesTextBlock.Text += DataReaderObject.ReadString(DataReaderObject.UnconsumedBufferLength); 
}
```

> When I set the read buffer length to higher than 4MB it fails to return any data. When I set it lower than 4MB (say 32KB) it just returns that 32KB.

The `readBufferLength` parameter is setting for [`DataReader.LoadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader#Windows_Storage_Streams_DataReader_LoadAsync_System_UInt32_) method that means the count of bytes to load into the intermediate buffer. So that if you set it with a higher value than the data length, it should work.But avoid to set the buffer too big. If you set the `readBufferLength` less than the data length, `await loadAsyncTask` will return the buffer length, and still left data need load. But in your code snippet, you only continue load with `while (bytesRead == 0)`, so that in this case you only load once with data length same to `readBufferLength`. You may need to continue `LoadAsync` with `while (bytesRead == ReadBufferLength)`.

> I don't know the read buffer length

Also you may try to use [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) which looks more simple. For example:

```
Stream streamIn = EventHandlerForDevice.Current.Device.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
string response = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
```